# Cannot find User with provided user_id parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to rails and trying to learn the framework by creating a Twitter Clone App. I can`t understand the error message as the code is more or less the same as the one i have in my sessions controller. What I'm basically trying to do is to save a new post in my db and then redirect back to the users show page.

So here's my code:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = Post.new(posts_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @user , notice: "You have now written a new Tweet"
```

My error message:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#create
Couldn't find User without an ID

The Tweets get saved in my db. But I'm having problems with the redirect. It works when I write in the ID manually though.

Comment: Give us the error message and route to your 'create' action (your URL). Params will give you the user_id from the URL you set up in you route.

Comment: Read some more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-purpose-of-the-rails-router

Comment: This is the url: http://localhost:3000/posts. I use resources :posts in my routes file. How can i access POST data?

Comment: One way to fix this would be to nest the post resource under a User resource so that your route looks like this: /users/1/posts.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not sending user_id with your POST requests. I am pretty sure that your tweet is not associated with any user for now. You have to use an authentication library such as [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to persist user login.

If you use this library, you can just use current_user method instead of doing

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]
```

Doing the above code is not also good because anyone can manipulate user_id in the POST form data to post a tweet for another user. If you have any question, please comment :)

Comment: If you need any help with devise, i can help you.

Comment: I made it work by changing User.find(params[:user_id] to User.find(session[:user_id]). My user id is associated with the tweets, checked my db.